# Subsets sharing at most $i$ elements

Tags: combinatorics

Assume I have a set $S$ of $N$ elements and I create subsets with $k$ elements from it. With no additional property the number of possible such subsets will be $N \choose k$.

Now I want my subsets to satisfy some additional rules $R_i$:

Given a set $X$ of subsets of $S$ with $k$ elements (i.e. $\forall A \in X, A \subset S , \#A=k$), $X$ satisfies $R_i$ if and only if for all $A$ and $B$ in $X$, $A$ and $B$ share at most $i$ elements, i.e. $\forall A , B \in X, \#(A \cap B) \le i$. Let's call $S_i$ the set of all such $X$ satisfying $R_i$.

I want to know how large a set satisfying $R_i$ can be, i.e. what is $M_i = \max_{X \in S_i} \#X $

For example if $N=1000$ and $k=10$, trivially we have $M_9 = {1000 \choose 10}$: the largest ensemble of subsets of $10$ elements that share at most $9$ with one another is exactly the set of all possible combinations of $10$ elements out of $1000$.

Similarly at the other extreme, still for $N=1000$ and $k=10$, we have $M_0 = 1000/10=100$.

Is there a formula or clever (not brute force) algorithm to compute other less trivial cases for $i=1,2,\dots8$?

BTW even if there is a nice formula, I'll ultimately want to implement a way to get a maximal $X$...

Comment: I regard this as one of those rare problems where you might use a computer simulation, for moderately sized values of the variables, **not** to solve the problem, but instead to **uncover patterns** in the answers to individual situations.  These patterns might lead you to elegant insights that might not otherwise have occurred to you.  In fact, you could use a separate simulation, for each different value of one of the variables.

Comment: The issue is I'm not even sure how to write such simulation properly, since apart from brute forcing it seems very easy (like often in combinatorics) to miss some cases or count others multiple times. And brute forcing will probably explode even for rather low values... But hey if no one has better ideas I might have to go down there...

Comment: Suppose that you start with $S = \{1,2,\cdots, 20\}$, with $k = 6$, and $i = 3.$  Then you initially have $\binom{20}{6}$ subsets.  Assume that the first one is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$  Now, eliminate all subsets that contain any 4 of the elements from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$  Now consider the second subset as being $\{1,2,3,7,8,9\}.$  Now eliminate all subsets that contain any 4 of the elements from $\{1,2,3,7,8,9\}.$  Now, this is where the fun starts.  You have some choices for the 3rd subset.  Explore each possible choice for the 3rd subset as a separate simulation, seeing where it leads.

Comment: One topic to search for is "design theory", which often treats the case where the pairwise intersections all have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is known in the literature as a *constant weight binary code* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-weight_code)). Specifically, if $A(n,d,w)$ is the maximum number of binary vectors, each with $w$ ones and $n-w$ zeroes, such that the Hamming distance between any two codewords is $d$, then the largest possible size of your set of sets would be $A(N,2(k-i) ,k)$.

Finding the maximal set is an open problem, and the best known known constructions for $X$ and best bounds are listed on [Andries E. Brouwer's website](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/Andw.html), along with known upper bounds on what is possible.

In general, if you want to find a set $X$ which is "good enough," and you have a comptuer you can program, then lexcodes are the way to go. Simply iterate through the list of all subsets of size $k$ in lexicographic order, and when you find a subset $S$ which shares no more than $i$ elements with everything in your current code, then add $S$ to the code.